# Full-wave center-tapped transformer output voltage

Tags: voltage, transformer, rectifier

I have a full-wave center-tapped transformer circuit with input voltage of 220 V.

How do I get an output voltage of 15 V? What equations should I use?

Here is the circuit:

[image]

Comment: What is a centre tapped rectifier?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: It's the transformer that's centre-tapped. You need to fix the title and the question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am still a beginner

Comment: You must reply.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. Centre-tapped transformer with full-wave rectification.*

Because there is no smoothing capacitor you just need a 15-0-15 V transformer. (You will lose about 0.7 V because of the diode drops so your actual output voltage will be 14.3 V DC.)

If you want smoothing you will be adding capacitors which will increase the average DC output voltage. There are many, many articles explaining this on the web.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsD46k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. A more usual way of drawing the same circuit with the power-supply on the left and the load on the right.*

---

From the comments:

> I want to understand it and what about the value of resistance between the two diodes.

It should be clearer in Figure 2 that the resistor is the load (whatever is being powered by the power-supply). It could, for example, be a light bulb or a motor.

One thing to watch is that the transformer will have a maximum power rating, usually in VA (volt-amps). In a real circuit you need to make sure that the current drawn by the load (R) is not greater than the transformer can supply without overheating.

See [Electronics Tutorials](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_6.html?utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F) for a good introduction.

Comment: I am a newbie into this. I want to understand it and what about the value of resistance between the two diodes. I need to do a circuit simulation using a program like proteus

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Using Max VA rating compute V/I and raise the R by 30% as the minimum R derated for power factor when you add a Cap.  The RC =T must be about 80 ms = 8/2f for ~10% ripple is a rough estimate

Comment: @Tony, that's likely to be as much use to the OP as a chocolate teapot.

Comment: I guess that for him to learn how to specify Vmin, Vmean, Vmax at rated R for 70% PF

Comment: Compute KVL during Charge pulse then Discharge decay to 90% of Vmax for 10% ripple

Comment: There is no requirement in the question for a smoothed DC output. Give the guy/gal a chance to figure out how a rectifier driving a resistor works first.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks, The link you provided was helpful. Can you suggest me a name of a book about this ?

Answer (score 1):

How about you do your KVL homework on sinewaves, source voltage, turns ratio and peak to full-wave conversion charts to proof and I'll show you the answer.

I used 240Vrms 50Hz because I assumed you were not in Canada. Correct me if I was wrong.

My diodes conducted 0.73Vpk into 100 Ohms. But you can assume 0.7V

[image]

[My simulation using arbitrary load R of 100 Ohms](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.00019999999999999998%200.8031194996067259%2053%205%2050%0Av%20112%20192%20112%20128%200%201%2050%20340%200%201.5707963267948966%200.5%0Aw%20112%20128%20160%20128%200%0Aw%20400%20128%20432%20160%200%0Ad%20336%20128%20400%20128%202%20default%0Ad%20336%20192%20400%20192%202%20default%0Aw%20432%20160%20400%20192%200%0Aw%20160%20192%20112%20192%200%0Ar%20464%20160%20464%20192%200%20100%0Ax%20487%20168%20522%20171%204%2020%20load%0A169%20160%20128%20224%20128%200%204%200.132%20-0.21775458314524093%201.714390808205124e-7%200.03552432686194651%200.99%0Ap%2048%20128%2048%20160%201%204%0Ap%20-32%20128%20-32%20192%201%201%0Aw%20112%20192%2048%20192%200%0Aw%20-32%20192%2048%20192%200%0Aw%20112%20128%2048%20128%200%0Aw%2048%20128%20-32%20128%200%0Aw%2048%20160%2048%20192%200%0Aw%20336%20160%20336%20192%200%0Aw%20336%20128%20256%20128%200%0Aw%20256%20128%20224%20128%200%0Aw%20256%20192%20336%20192%200%0Aw%20256%20192%20224%20192%200%0Ap%20256%20128%20256%20192%201%201%0Ap%20336%20128%20336%20160%201%204%0Ag%20224%20160%20224%20176%200%0Aw%20464%20160%20432%20160%200%0Ag%20464%20192%20464%20208%200%0Ao%200%201%200%2029450%20340%200.0001%200%202%200%203%0Ao%207%201%200%2029450%2021.48689673645305%200.0001%200%202%207%203%0Ao%2023%201%200%2013066%2044.4384403471893%200.0001%200%201%0A) and Vrms is computed on plots with Vmax and Vmin shown.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, Like I said I am a total beginner to this

Comment: You must understand how it works before the math

Comment: Well, I know that it unifies the direction of the current by using the diode as a switch that only lets current flow in one direction